# .focus() not adding class with .parent()

Tags: jquery, button, focus, parent, addclass

Having an issue I can't seem to shake. I have several table rows that I'm using jQuery to highlight whenever they are clicked. Some of my rows have a single input/button/checkbox/textarea so they aren't delineated by spans and I'm using another function that only has two parents. Those work fine. So does the addressed "span input." "span button" on the other hand isn't adding the active class. The weird thing is, if I'm looking at it in a desktop browser and I click it, make another application's window active or add a new tab in the browser and then click back to it, it's highlighted as it should be.

No clue what's going on. Please help! Thanks so much!

HTML:

```
<tr>
    <td class="input">
        <span>
            <label for="buttonA">ButtonA Label</label>
            <button name="buttonA" type="button"/>ButtonA</button>
        </span>
        <span>
            <label for="buttonB">ButtonB Label</label>
            <button name="buttonB" type="button"/>ButtonB</button>
        </span>
    </td>
    <td class="unit">
        Unit
    </td>
    <td class="info">
        Description or additional info</br>
        With multiple lines
    </td>
    <td class="action">
        <div id="delete" class="btn"><img src="delete_icon.png"></div>
        <div id="drag" class="btn"><img src="drag_icon.png"></div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

CSS:

```
.active {
    background: rgb(227,238,255) !important;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$("span input,span button").focus(function() {
    $(this).parent().parent().parent().addClass('active');
});
```

Comment: Don't use multiple `.parent()` calls.  Use `.closest("tr")` or whatever item you are trying to select.  This is much less brittle and will work regardless of how many parents there are in between.

Comment: In your question, it is not clear what exact steps you take when it does not work.  Do you click on the button?  Do you tab to the button?

Comment: @jfriend00 .closest is fantastic, thanks! Definitely cleans up the rest of my jQuery a bit. Unfortunately I'm still having the same problem with the buttons in the spans. Everything else still works.

In my code it's supposed to change the color of the whole row when anywhere on the row is clicked. Any td, on the button itself, etc.

Comment: @jfriend00 Oh, man. It works when I tab to it, but not when I click it. What does that mean? :/

Comment: What happens if you assign a tabindex value to the button, or use an input of type button instead? (Not all elements acts the same on the focus event).

Comment: @MorganJeffrey - it probably means that the focus isn't actually going to the button on a click.  You could add "click" to the event handler (so you do the same action on a click too) or there's probably a way to make sure the button takes focus when you click on it.

Comment: I also think you should use ```click``` and ```return false```, since there is event delegation and your ```parent().parent()``` might not always be the ```tr```. If you use ```closest``` the problem may exist!

Comment: @Dr.Flink If I make it an input I have the exact same issue. Nothing seems to change. It already seems to work when I tab to it, just not when it is clicked.

Comment: @jfriend00 I guess I should also mention that this is in my jQuery. The buttons are already being focused when the row is clicked.

    `$("tr").click(function() {
        $(this).find("input,textarea,select,button").focus().select();
    });`

Comment: @MorganJeffrey Seems like this is an issue for the Google Chrome browser, which is the browser you are using now, yes? :)
Use the Click event instead as earlier mentioned (or a combination of the two, using trigger('focus') on the click event).

Comment: This jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/rmAA9/ works in every browser I tried (Firefox, Chrome, IE9, Safari.  What browser are you seeing the problem in?